# Program w/ 2 loops and timing and such

Tags: microprocessor, programmer, timing

So let's say i have a prog that has a fast loop @e 64uS, and a slow loop @e 8mS.  If the fast loop takes 34uS to execute do I need to make sure the slow loop can execute in 30uS, so as to not be interrupted??

It seems like sometimes if one loop keeps interrupting the other bad things will happen.  Is this true>?

Comment: Can you be more informative and maybe share the code. Did you setup either interrupts or priorities?

Comment: What makes you think "bad things will happen"? An OS is basically a loop that gets interrupted over and over again but it keeps working. This is not a problem if your code handles the interrupts correctly.

Comment: What does "@e" mean?

Comment: prog in C, so i think the 'bad things' were the result of not saving wreg and status into temp variables when an interrupt occurs

Comment: Notice this is teetering on the brink of being closed? You need to add some context ASAP, before that 5th vote to close happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a microprocessor with its own hardware interrupts, you should be able to set two hardware timers (unless it's a very basic micro) and then assign an interrupt routine to each, set the timers up with the correct period, and it'll all just happen.

The slow one will get "paused" if the fast one happens while it's executing. When neither is executing, you're free to execute non time-sensitive code in the main() loop.

Other answers so far seem to assume an operating system with its own priority/interrupt system, which is a big overhead in time, space and complexity on most micros. Doing it with hardware timers which can interrupt in hardware will give much quicker response.

Without more details (MCU, language, more description of code...) it's very hard to be much more helpful.

As you sound like this is a bit new to you, I would suggest reading up on how to write code that doesn't fall over itself when one interrupt routine changes something in the middle of the other one doing something - it does require a bit of thought! If the timings are *very* critical you may need to tweak timer values to allow for the time taken for the interrupt to happen, some timers can give period+/-1 errors due to the way the counters work - ask me how I know!

Comment: how do you know? related question: is there an ideal location for uart writes? i'm guessing this would fall into non-critical and fit into the main loop..

Comment: Because one of our timers (Programmable Interrupt Timer) is subject to a bug, more relating to the explanation of operation in the datasheet about the rollover value if memory serves - does it rollover AND decrement in the same cycle, does it rollover from 1 to 255 or from 0 to 255, that sort of thing. Over a long time it can lead to unexpected timing drifts and a few other unintended consequences...

Comment: ...ref the UART writes, it depends really. If your UART has enough buffer then you can probably write to it from main() when needed and leave the hardware to work. However, if it doesn't have enough buffer, or if you have to send a lot of data, you might want to implement a software buffer or other flow-control and service that buffer in the UART's "I'm ready to transmit" interrupt call. It's processor & application-specific and the only real answer is to think about it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to program logic in your loops. Make them aware of each other. An idea, you can set a global variable at the beginning of the loop and at the end of the loop changing the global variable from 0 to 1 or whatever. Make the other loop check to see if the global variable is true then run the loop, if not then wait x amount of time. Simple if statement should be used.

What language are you programming in?

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is have one single loop which monitors a real-time clock source (such as some bus cycle count register or anything of that sort), looks at a schedule table, and calls the registered functions at the correct times.  If a periodic action that takes place every 8 ms is scheduled at the same time as an action that takes place every 64 us, perhaps the 64 us one can take priority.  If the 8 ms action is delayed by 30 us, it's not a big perturbation in its period.  Which action is run first if they are scheduled at the same time can be resolved by having a priority field attached to the action.